# Changing of google analytics data chart dimensions on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to change session data chart dimensions when user click one of these buttons "Hourly","Day","Month" .
where  should i put event handler , my code is :

```
    <div class="chart-section">
   <div class="filter">
      <button id="hourly" class="btn btn-   default">Hourly</button>
           <button id="day"  class="btn btn-default">Day</button>
         <button id="week"  class="btn btn-default">Week</button>
    <button id="month" class="btn btn-default">Month</button>
</div>
<section id="timeline">

</section>
```

and

```
 var timeline1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        reportType: 'ga',
        query: {
            'dimensions': 'ga:date',
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
            'start-date': '30daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday',
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'LINE',
            container: 'timeline',
            options: {width: '100%'}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, i guess you can simply use, for example:

```
$('#hourly').click(function() {
  // changes go here
});
```

Comment: Ok,i know that,but how to change the dimensions after  clicking on button